# Java 8 lambda efficient method solution

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-stream

**I want to improve the code more efficiently and clearly using java 8. Can someone tell me, thus thank you so much**
I want to get idList and nameList from the checks-giving by a generator.
The code is below this.

```
LocalDateTime newStart = LocalDateTime.now();
List<Check> checks = generateCheck();
List<String> idListNew = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> nameListNew = new ArrayList<>();
checks.forEach(ck -> {
    idListNew.add(ck.getId());
    nameListNew.add(ck.getName());
});
```

Comment: i guess you already have effective way

Comment: think over iterating once versus twice as a trade-off and what is the `newStart` required for?

Comment: I think you meant efficient, our code is already effective.

Comment: Use `List<String> idListNew = new ArrayList<>(checks.size()); List<String> nameListNew = new ArrayList<>(checks.size());` to initialize the lists with the required capacity. Besides that, there is no opportunity to increase the performance.

Comment: Thak you so much

Comment: It might be late but FYI, You need to create a custom collector. This will avoid the side effects. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203776/java-stream-grouping-by-multiple-fields-individually-in-declarative-way-in-singl.

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine consumers, like:

```
Consumer<Check> idConsumer = ck -> idListNew.add(Check::getId);
Consumer<Check> nameConsumer = ck -> idListNew.add(Check::getName);

checks.stream().forEach(idConsumer.andThen(nameConsumer));
```

Comment: Thank you that helps me understand consumer well.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 Streams and Lambda based solution without side effects.

```
LocalDateTime newStart = LocalDateTime.now();
List<Check> checks = generateCheck();
List<String> idListNew = checks.stream().map(Check::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> nameListNew = checks.stream().map(Check::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: is this effective way by considering the performance with the original solution

Comment: @janith1024 I think that is indeed better in performance, because t involves streams, and it also provides additional flexiblity.

Comment: iterating  twice that I test it slowly

Comment: While this solution may be not effective, but I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @DhruvSinghal But here two stream creation happen. Creating stream is expensive. But next operations after create of  stream is efficient. Creating two stream is less efficient than single iterate.

Comment: @janith1024 The Original Solution creates Side Effects which is a big no when using Streams. Streams are not about entirely performance. Streams allow declarative style of programming (What to do) not imperative style of programming (How to do). The simple for loop is much faster than streams but you can make so many mistakes writing the loop logic (you can initiate a for loop with int i = 1 and set the exit condition to i < 10 when you really want to loop from 1 to 10). Read this for more info http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2014/11/java-8-not-paradigm-shift-just_12.html

Comment: @shazin you are correct. The question was efficient. So I comment on efficient in performance. Not in clean code and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Java 12 or above, then you could use the `teeing` collector:

```java
Merger m = checks.stream()
    .collect(teeing(
        mapping(Check::getId, toList()),
        mapping(Check::getName, toList()),
        Merger::new));

System.out.println(m.ids());
System.out.println(m.names());
```

<sup>`mapping`, `teeing` and `toList` are static imports from `java.util.stream.Collectors`.</sup>

Where `Merger` is a container class of the following form:

```java
private static record Merger(List<String> ids, List<String> names) { }

// Records are a language feature since Java 15. Otherwise, you could instead
// write this class yourself:
class Merger {
    List<String> ids;
    List<String> names;
    // All-args constructor and getters
}

// Or you could just use an existing type like Map.Entry or Pair.
```

---

The advantage of the abovementioned solution is that it traverses the list once, which would otherwise impose a performance penalty if the list is very large. Your own solution has the same advantage regarding this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try It If I am using Java 12.

Answer (score 0):

Same above answer but more effective performance:

```
LocalDateTime newStart = LocalDateTime.now();
List<Check> checks = generateCheck();
List<String>[] temp = 
                checks.stream().map((e) -> new String[] {e.getId(), e.getName()}).collect(() -> 
                    {
                        List<String>[] arr = 
                                new ArrayList[2];
                        arr[0] = new ArrayList<>();
                        arr[1] = new ArrayList<>();
                        return arr;
                    }
                , (list, e) -> {
                    list[0].add(e[0]);
                    list[1].add(e[1]);
                }, (list, otherList) -> {
                    list[0].addAll(otherList[0]);
                    list[1].addAll(otherList[1]);
                });
List<String> idListNew = temp[0];
List<String> nameListNew = temp[1];
```

Comment: I am so sorry that I will tell you that It is more slowly when I tested it.  by the way, thank you so much.

Comment: I was learning more operation from your solution. thank you so much.