# Java Stream Grouping by multiple fields individually in declarative way in single loop

Tags: java, java-stream, declarative-programming, groupingby

I googled for it but I mostly found cases for grouping by aggregated fields or on to alter response of stream but not the scenario below:

I have a class `User` with fields `category` and `marketingChannel`.

I have to write a method in the declarative style that accepts a list of users and counts users based on
`category` and also based on `marketingChannel` individually (i.e not `groupingBy(... ,groupingBy(..))` ).

I am unable to do it in a single loop. This is what I have to achieve.

I coded few methods as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = User.createDemoList();
        imperative(users);
        declerativeMultipleLoop(users);
        declerativeMultipleColumn(users);
    }
    
    public static void imperative(List<User> users){
        Map<String, Integer> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> channelMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(User user : users){
           Integer  value = categoryMap.getOrDefault(user.getCategory(), 0);
           categoryMap.put(user.getCategory(), value+1);
           value = channelMap.getOrDefault(user.getMarketingChannel(), 0);
           channelMap.put(user.getMarketingChannel(), value+1);
        }
        System.out.println("imperative");
        System.out.println(categoryMap);
        System.out.println(channelMap);
    }
    
    public static void declerativeMultipleLoop(List<User> users){
        Map<String, Long> categoryMap = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            User::getCategory, Collectors.counting()));
        Map<String, Long> channelMap = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            User::getMarketingChannel, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println("declerativeMultipleLoop");
        System.out.println(categoryMap);
        System.out.println(channelMap);
    }
    
    public static void declerativeMultipleColumn(List<User> users){
        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            User::getCategory,
            Collectors.groupingBy(User::getMarketingChannel, 
            Collectors.counting())));
       
        System.out.println("declerativeMultipleColumn");
        System.out.println("groupingBy category and marketChannel");
        System.out.println(map);
        
        Map<String, Long> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Long> channelMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            String category = entry.getKey();
            Integer count = entry.getValue().size();
            Long value = categoryMap.getOrDefault(category,0L);
            categoryMap.put(category, value+count);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Long> channelEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()){
                String channel = channelEntry.getKey();
                Long channelCount = channelEntry.getValue();
                Long channelValue = channelMap.getOrDefault(channel,0L);
                channelMap.put(channel, channelValue+channelCount);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After Implerative Loop on above.");
        System.out.println(categoryMap);
        System.out.println(channelMap);
    }
}
class User{
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private String marketChannel;
    
    public User(String name, String category, String marketChannel){
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.marketChannel = marketChannel;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getCategory(){
        return this.category;
    }
    public String getMarketingChannel(){
        return this.marketChannel;
    }
    
     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, user.name) &&
                Objects.equals(category, user.category) &&
                Objects.equals(marketChannel, user.marketChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, category, marketChannel);
    }
    public static List<User> createDemoList(){
        return Arrays.asList(
            new User("a", "student","google"),
            new User("b", "student","bing"),
            new User("c", "business","google"),
            new User("d", "business", "direct")
            );
    }
```

> The method `declerativeMultipleLoop` is declarative but it has a separate loop for each field. Complexity : O(noOfFields * No of users)

> The problem is in `declerativeMultipleColumn` Method as I end up writing imperative code and multiple loops.

> I want to write the above method in completely declarative and as efficient as possible. i.e Complexity : O(No of users)

Sample output:

> imperative
> {business=2, student=2}
> {direct=1, google=2, bing=1}
> declerativeMultipleLoop
> {business=2, student=2}
> {direct=1, google=2, bing=1}
> declerativeMultipleColumn
> groupingBy category and marketChannel
> {business={direct=1, google=1}, student={google=1, bing=1}}
> After Implerative Loop on above.
> {business=2, student=2}
> {direct=1, google=2, bing=1}

Comment: The best route is probably to write a custom collector.

Comment: yup, your answer works. Thanks for the help. @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your requirement it is to use a single stream operation that results in 2 separate maps. That is going to require a structure to hold the maps and a collector to build the structure. Something like the following:

```
class Counts {
    public final Map<String, Integer> categoryCounts = new HashMap<>();
    public final Map<String, Integer> channelCounts = new HashMap<>();

    public static Collector<User,Counts,Counts> countsCollector() {
        return Collector.of(Counts::new, Counts::accept, Counts::combine, CONCURRENT, UNORDERED);
    }

    private Counts() { }

    private void accept(User user) {
        categoryCounts.merge(user.getCategory(), 1, Integer::sum);
        channelCounts.merge(user.getChannel(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    private Counts combine(Counts other) {
        other.categoryCounts.forEach((c, v) -> categoryCounts.merge(c, v, Integer::sum));
        other.channelCounts.forEach((c, v) -> channelCounts.merge(c, v, Integer::sum));
        return this;
    }
}
```

That can then be used as a collector:

```
Counts counts = users.stream().collect(Counts.countsCollector());
counts.categoryCounts.get("student")...
```

(Opinion only: the distinction between imperative and declarative is pretty arbitrary in this case. Defining stream operations feels pretty procedural to me (as opposed to the equivalent in, say, Haskell)).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I was exactly looking for this. Just a small change Counts class method name should be either merge or combine. Right now, The code will not compile b/c merge function is not defined. I rename combine to merge and It works.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree with you that the difference is arbitrary. But I wanted to utilize parallel stream method. So you see with this I can change stream to parallel stream though We need to change the HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap, right?
Also, then this merge function will be used. i.e in case of parallel stream, right?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FarazAhmed not my answer. But no, you don’t need to change to a `ConcurrentHashMap` - Java streams guarantee that collectors are not concurrently accessed; it’s scatter gather - that’s what the `combine` method is for.

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for you answer. Thanks alot man. Sorry I missed your name by seeing the comments only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) two maps in a single [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
            new User("a", "student", "google"),
            new User("b", "student", "bing"),
            new User("c", "business", "google"),
            new User("d", "business", "direct"));
    Map<String, Integer> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> channelMap = new HashMap<>();

    // group users into maps
    users.forEach(user -> {
        categoryMap.compute(user.getCategory(),
                (key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
        channelMap.compute(user.getChannel(),
                (key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
    });
    // output
    System.out.println(categoryMap); // {business=2, student=2}
    System.out.println(channelMap); // {direct=1, google=2, bing=1}
}
```

```java
static class User {
    private final String name, category, channel;

    public User(String name, String category, String channel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getCategory() { return this.category; }
    public String getChannel() { return this.channel; }
}
```